# powershell - Check multiple user and exclude duplicate user and add count

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am tasked to create a script that can perform the following task. Example: We have a Domain ABC.

There are 4 security groups, named A, B, C and D.

Peter is member of A and B group. 
David is member of B and C group. 
John is member of A group. 
B group is also a member A group.

We want to find the total count of user in A, B groups. Those user that already in the group will be exclude in the count which mean exclude duplicate users count. Based on above, the script will show a total count of A & B = 3 users instead 5 users. I tried to work on a script that will count the user in A and B groups and also any group exist in A and B group. If John reside in A and B, the script will just add 1 count. Also If David is in B group but not in A group, it will add 1 count.

**Edit:** after amending the code with you guys' help, there is no error. However the result shown is empty.

```
$groups = $A_group, $B_Group
$gm     = @()
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $gm += Get-ADGroupMember $group |
           where {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'} |
           select SamAccountName
}
($gm.samaccountname | Select -Unique).Count
Write-Output $total = ($gm.samaccountname | Select -Unique).Count
```

Comment: where do you define your $total variable?

Comment: How *exactly* did the code "not work"? What was the expected result? What was the actual result? Did you get errors? What did they say?

Comment: `$total = ($gm.samaccountname | Select -Unique).Count; Write-Output $total`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are nested groups [Groups inside groups], the only thing you are missing is the `-recursive` parameter for `Get-ADGroupMember`. This will get the users inside the nested ADGroup B as well instead of just returning the ADGroup B Name.

Change this line to as below:

```
$gm += Get-ADGroupMember $group -Recursive | where objectclass -eq 'user' | select SamAccountName
```

I don't know what the last line is doing.[Seems wrong and unnecessary] The below line is enough to get you the total count.

```
$total = ($gm.samaccountname | Select -Unique).count
```

Comment: I got an error when ran the code. 

char:17
+            where <<<<  objectclass -eq 'user' | 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
 
Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "objectclass" value of type "System.String"
 to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".

Comment: At ps1:28 char:17
+            where <<<<  objectclass -eq 'user' | 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: Not sure why there no reply instead have to use the comment?

Comment: @Power988 Because you're supposed to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46290894/edit) if you need to provide additional information. SO is a Q&A site, not a web forum.

Comment: Regarding the error, `where objectclass -eq 'user'` is an abbreviated notation that was introduced with PowerShell v3. In v2 you must use the regular notation: `where {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'}`.

Comment: Thank. The code working now but the result is empty. Guess I miss out define the $total ?